# Convert list to csv but data has ',' in it

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to convert a list to csv but some data hava ',' in them. So when I write

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(elements)
```

elements being my list name, the data which contains a "," is sent to the next column, but it is a part of a single name. For Eg. `Smith, CA. SO` the CA moves to the next column.
What can I do?

Comment: set the quotechar to the quoting mechanism your application uses - most likely the default `"`.

Comment: Can you give an example?  Using your code with the list `[['a', 'b,c', 'd'],[1,2,3]]` with delimiter `','` and `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, it works perfectly for me.  Why doesn't it for you?

Comment: @RayToal Open the file in MS Excel afterwards, you'll see that b and c are on different columns. Then try with Tim Pietzcker's solution
(Tested on MS Excel 2007).

Comment: If you want to open it in Excel, best to use the default dialect of `'excel'`.

Comment: Okay but the question didn't say anything specific about Excel.  As a Python script, the OP's code was just fine.  Not being able to open in Excel is a completely different question. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you should be opening the file using the `newline=''` parameter (read the docs for the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)).

Then, choose `"` as your quote character so other CSV tools (Excel?) that expect quotes can react correctly to your file:

```
with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `csv.QUOTE_ALL`.

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL)

```
csv.QUOTE_ALL
Instructs writer objects to quote all fields.
```

If you are using a special quote char, the application you are using to read the csv needs to be configured to use it as the quote char

Comment: `QUOTE_ALL` is unnecessary. `QUOTE_MINIMAL` already quotes all the fields where that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, but note this won't be readable in Excel as someone commented.

```
import csv

elements = [['Last1, First1','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded|Quote'],
            ['Last2, First2','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded|Quote'],
            ['Last3, First3','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded|Quote'],
            ['Last4, First4','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded|Quote']]

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(elements)

with open('out.csv') as fp:
    print(fp.read())

with open('out.csv', 'r', newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, quotechar='|')
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
|Last1, First1|,|City, State|,12345,111-22-3333,|Embedded||Quote|
|Last2, First2|,|City, State|,12345,111-22-3333,|Embedded||Quote|
|Last3, First3|,|City, State|,12345,111-22-3333,|Embedded||Quote|
|Last4, First4|,|City, State|,12345,111-22-3333,|Embedded||Quote|

['Last1, First1', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded|Quote']
['Last2, First2', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded|Quote']
['Last3, First3', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded|Quote']
['Last4, First4', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded|Quote']
```

If you actually want to open the `.csv` file in Excel, use the default `dialect` parameter. Also you `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to support non-ASCII characters and also provide the byte order mark (BOM) signature that Excel requires to read the .csv properly:

```
#! coding=utf8
import csv

elements = [['Last1, First1','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded"Quote'],
            ['多路能, 马克','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded"Quote'],
            ['Last3, First3','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded"Quote'],
            ['Last4, First4','City, State',12345,'111-22-3333','Embedded"Quote']]

with open('out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerows(elements)

with open('out.csv','rb') as fp:
    print(fp.read().decode())

with open('out.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
"Last1, First1","City, State",12345,111-22-3333,"Embedded""Quote"
"多路能, 马克","City, State",12345,111-22-3333,"Embedded""Quote"
"Last3, First3","City, State",12345,111-22-3333,"Embedded""Quote"
"Last4, First4","City, State",12345,111-22-3333,"Embedded""Quote"

['Last1, First1', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded"Quote']
['多路能, 马克', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded"Quote']
['Last3, First3', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded"Quote']
['Last4, First4', 'City, State', '12345', '111-22-3333', 'Embedded"Quote']
```

Answer (score 0):

The values that have to be quoted will be quoted, automatically. For example, if you use `,` as delimiter, the value "Smith, CA" has to be quoted since it contains a `,`.

Your question does not say anything about how the `elements` variable looks, so I'm making a guess here. If you have elements in an iterable and each element looks something like `['Smith, CA', 1, someothervalue]`, the code you posted works just fine. I completed your code example as follows:

```
import csv

elements = [['Smith, CA', 1, 'salad'], ['Doe, NY', 2, 'soup']]

with open('out.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(elements)
```

It will produce the following output:

```
|Smith, CA|,1,salad
|Doe, NY|,2,soup
```

Note 1: Since you are using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`, it is only values that *need* to be quoted that will be. Other values like `1` or `'salad'` are not quoted.

Note 2: Using `|` as a quotechar is not very common, as @TimPietzcker just noted. But it works.